# How do I view inline images in w3m?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, graphics, iterm

I am using a Mac (El Capitan), and trying to use `w3m`. But I don't see images when browsing pages.

> My question is: I want to view inline images in w3m, but don't find a way to do so.

I have been told that `w3m` can display inline images, and seen some video examples. But all the tutorials I found use Linux or the like, and I can't seem to make w3m display inline images.

I opened `w3m` in a terminal (either `xterm` or `iterm2`), and pressed <kbd>o</kbd> and set the `display inline image` option to yes, and re-launches `w3m`, but nothing happens.

Some say that one should install `w3m-img`, but I cannot find a package named as such. Others say that one should enable frame buffer; however, I don't know how to do that either.

Any help or reference is sincerely appreciated.

**P.S.**
In `item2` I can display images on the terminal, but, when using `w3m`, still no images appear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: w3m with inline images on macos]

Things you need to make this happen on macos:

**1. Terminal emulator that supports [sixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel)**

iTerm2 recently [added sixel support](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/commit/0d0003d9d20b7de3a3ffd815950acb7cc9777c38) for viewing inline images. You'l need iterm 3.3 or later, which at time of writing is in beta, available in the test releases section of the [downloads page](https://www.iterm2.com/downloads.html).

**2. Utility for converting images to sixel format**

I used [img2sixel](https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel).

```
  git clone https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel # Download the source code
  pushd libsixel # switch to the directory containing the source
  ./configure # This generates compilation settings for your OS
  make # Compile the program
  export SIXEL_DIR=${PWD} # Store current directory for reference later

  # Test it
  ./converters/img2sixel images/snake.png #should display in your terminal :)
```

**3. w3m build with sixel support**

Follow the [sixel readme in tats/w3m](https://github.com/tats/w3m/blob/master/doc/README.sixel)

```
  popd # Don't clone w3m within the img2sixel dir
  git clone https://github.com/tats/w3m
  pushd w3m
  ./configure --enable-image
  make

  # Test it 
  W3M_IMG2SIXEL="${SIXEL_DIR}/converters/img2sixel" ./w3m -sixel -o display_image=1 google.com
```

**4. Install**

If the above test worked, then the compiled img2sixel and w3m binaries can be copied into a dir referenced by `$PATH`, eg `/usr/local/bin` so you don't have to reference them explicitly each time you start w3m.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It will be of use when I want to use w3m again.

Comment: should be "pushd w3m"

Comment: Good spot @MartinPham, fixed.

Comment: In ubuntu, now you can just use `sudo apt install w3m-img`

Comment: Thank you! For me though, on Mac Catalina 10.15.6, step 3 > configure should be changed to `./configure --enable-image --with-imagelib=imlib2`. Then it worked.

Comment: What to do if the 3rd step test fails?

Comment: @nilon depends how it failed...

Comment: @mellow-yellow I am using Mojave10.14.6, the test worked for me with the `--with-imagelib=imlib2` (didn't work without it), but w3m doesn't show the images while browsing even after I put the binaries in `/usr/local/bin` (which I double-checked is in my `$PATH`). Any guess what might be going wrong? Just in case it might be shell dependent, I tried in all the three shells I have used -- `BASH`, `zsh`, and `fish`. (Moreover, I can verify that the binaries are in the path, for example, `img2sixel image.png` and `w3m wikileaks.org` both work from the home directory.)

Answer (score 3):

From https://ilyakava.tumblr.com/post/616300103655948288/terminal-web-browser-with-images-macos:

1. First, you’ll have to use iTerm 3.3 or later.
2. Install the image converter for the terminal:

   ```
   brew install libsixel
   ```
3. Install `w3m`:

   ```
   brew install w3m
   ```
4. There is no image support in `w3m` by default. To enable it:

   1. Run:

      ```
      brew edit w3m
      ```
   2. Change `--disable-image` to `--enable-image` and save. You may add a line `--with-imagelib=imlib2` if it doesn't work. Then:

      ```
      brew reinstall --build-from-source w3m
      ```
5. Launch `w3m` with:

   ```
   W3M_IMG2SIXEL=/usr/local/bin/img2sixel w3m -sixel -o display_image=1 google.com
   ```

Scrolling with the mouse lags and it is better to page up/down by holding the fn key with up and down arrows. Press Shift+h for the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

w3m should have enabled images. That's why it should be rebuilded from source. But brew has a bug and you need to copy formula before building. The following steps are tested on Apple M1 (on Intel you probably have other path to homebrew):

```sh
brew install iterm2 w3m libsixel
open /Applications/iTerm.app
# without copying formula brew reverts the changes and builds without image support
cp /opt/homebrew/opt/w3m/.brew/w3m.rb .
# use vim or any other editor
vim ./w3m.rb
# delete line: --disable-image
brew reinstall --build-from-source --formula ./w3m.rb
w3m -sixel google.com
# press o:
#   Display inline images -> YES -> OK
#   Run external viewer in background -> YES -> OK
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community fixed

Answer (score 0):

w3m has support for the Iterm2 image protocol. To enable it you can set the image protocol in your w3m config:

```
inline_img_protocol 3
imgdisplay iterm2
```